# Tweet from authenticated logged in twitter user

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I have a web app where people can log in through Twitter and by doing so authenticate the app to tweet on their behalf, I want to do this.

But the problem is that I cannot find any endpoints in the twitter API that would facilitate this,

I'm able to tweet from my own app using the Twitter npm package but I can't find a parameter to pass something like a user ID to tweet from a different twitter account using my App.

Do you maybe need the OAUTH token and secret to do this?

Comment: did you look at having a "sign in with twitter account" button? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/login-in-with-twitter

Comment: Yes I have that and found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have people sign in on your web page and get their `tokenSecret` and `token` from the login, put those in the place where the `access_token_key` and `access_token_secret` usually go when tweeting and send a regular `statuses/update/` POST request.